# Merge multiple txt files with same column names creating a new column from the filenames

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Merge multiple txt files with same column names, creating a new column from the file names. Looking for a unix solution.

eg.

file1.txt

```
country   player  age
USA       Ben     24
```

file2.txt

```
country   player  age
UK        John     27
```

file3.txt

```
country   player  age
Spain     Alex     28
Germany   Hubber   26
```

expected output 
merged_files.txt

```
filename   country   player  age
 file1      USA       Ben     24 
 file2      UK        John     27
 file3      Spain     Alex     28
 file3      Germany   Hubber   26
```

I tried `$ cat file*.txt > merged_files.txt`
How can I add the an additional column to the right from the filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk 'FNR==1{if (NR==1) print "filename", $0; next} {print FILENAME, $0}' file[123]

filename country   player  age
file1 USA       Ben     24
file2 UK        John     27
file3 Spain     Alex     28
file3 Germany   Hubber   26
```

To get tabular report:

```
awk 'FNR==1{if (NR==1) print "filename", $0; next} {print FILENAME, $0}' file[123] |
column -t

filename  country  player  age
file1     USA      Ben     24
file2     UK       John    27
file3     Spain    Alex    28
file3     Germany  Hubber  26
```

Comment: Thanks. What do I do if have more than 100 files with different names. How  I replace file[123] | column -t

Comment: OK, I git it now. awk 'FNR==1{if (NR==1) print "filename", $0; next} {print FILENAME, $0}' *txt > merged_files.txt